# The counter doesnt seem to increase when ever the edittext changes

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-edittext, switch-statement

Im using Edit-texts and i need when ever an edit-text is changed to increment a counter by one but the counter isnt working , I mean the app starts and everything but the counter doesnt seem to change please help here is the code

```
public class Numersys extends Activity implements TextWatcher  {
EditText mark1 ,mark2, mark3,mark4,mark5,mark6 , hr1 ,hr2,hr3,hr4,hr5,hr6;
EditText passed, currentavg;
TextView tvnewavg ;
Button calculate;
double marks , curAVG , NewAVG ;
String newCumAVG;


int counter , hrs , curHr , NewHr;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.numersys);

    mark1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1n);
    mark2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2n);
    mark3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark3n);
    mark4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark4n);
    mark5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark5n);
    mark6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark6n);


    hr1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ethour1);
    hr2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ethour2);
    hr3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ethour3);
    hr4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ethour4);
    hr5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ethour5);
    hr6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ethour6);


    passed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassCn);
    currentavg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCavgn);

    tvnewavg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcAVGn);

    mark1.addTextChangedListener(this);
    mark2.addTextChangedListener(this);
    mark3.addTextChangedListener(this);
    mark4.addTextChangedListener(this);
    mark5.addTextChangedListener(this);
    mark6.addTextChangedListener(this);

    calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAvgCalcn);
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(arg0.getId())
            {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:

                hrs=Integer.valueOf(hr1.getText().toString());

                marks=Double.valueOf(mark1.getText().toString())*Integer.valueOf(hr1.getText().toString());

                curHr=Integer.valueOf(passed.getText().toString());
                curAVG=Double.valueOf(currentavg.getText().toString())*curHr;

                NewHr= curHr+hrs;
                NewAVG= (marks+curAVG)/NewHr;





                break;
            case 2:

                hrs=Integer.valueOf(hr1.getText().toString())+Integer.valueOf(hr2.getText().toString());

                marks=Double.valueOf(mark1.getText().toString())*Integer.valueOf(hr1.getText().toString())
                        +Double.valueOf(mark2.getText().toString())*Integer.valueOf(hr2.getText().toString());

                curHr=Integer.valueOf(passed.getText().toString());
                curAVG=Double.valueOf(currentavg.getText().toString())*curHr;

                NewHr= curHr+hrs;
                NewAVG= (marks+curAVG)/NewHr;
                break;
            case 3:

                hrs=Integer.valueOf(hr1.getText().toString())+Integer.valueOf(hr2.getText().toString())
                +Integer.valueOf(hr3.getText().toString());

                marks=Double.valueOf(mark1.getText().toString())*Integer.valueOf(hr1.getText().toString())
                        +Double.valueOf(mark2.getText().toString())*Integer.valueOf(hr2.getText().toString())
                        +Double.valueOf(mark3.getText().toString())*Integer.valueOf(hr3.getText().toString());

                curHr=Integer.valueOf(passed.getText().toString());
                curAVG=Double.valueOf(currentavg.getText().toString())*curHr;

                NewHr= curHr+hrs;
                NewAVG= (marks+curAVG)/NewHr;
                break;
            case R.id.bAvgCalcn:

                newCumAVG=String.valueOf(NewAVG);
                tvnewavg.setText(newCumAVG);
            }
        }
    });


}




@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(mark1.hasFocus())
    {
        counter = counter+1;
    }
    if(mark2.hasFocus())
    {
        counter = counter+1;
    }
    if(mark3.hasFocus())
    {
        counter = counter+1;
    }
    if(mark4.hasFocus())
    {
        counter = counter+1;
    }
    if(mark5.hasFocus())
    {
        counter = counter+1;
    }
    if(mark6.hasFocus())
    {
        counter = counter+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question, did you set the listener to the editText box? also did you try to just put `counter += 1` in the `OnTextChanged` method without the `if(..)` blocks?

Comment: quick tip, instead of counter = counter+1; use counter++; does the same thing, much quicker and neater

Comment: You also havent shown where you defined the edittexts and the counter.

Comment: @kabuto178 I want a specific edittexts to increase the counter  :D

Comment: @xBroak thx i will , and here is the full code :D

Comment: Well you have 6 `editText` boxes and 1 counter variable, in any case all boxes will increment the one variable. If you wanted to keep track of each `editText` you would need 6 different counters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your trying to increment a counter that has no value:

```
int counter;

counter = counter+1;
```

should in theory do nothing?

Try setting counter as:

```
int counter = 0;
```

give that a go and let me know!

Comment: Have you tried logging the text changed listener to see if its even being called?